# Different behavior of special character ( ? ) in Fedora from different location

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, fedora

I have an rpm application which gets installed in a specific location in Fedora OS.

My application has the capability to process special character (?).

When I run from the installation path, my application gets the `?` argument. However, when I copy to different location, I get `1` as the argument when user gives `?` using my application.

**Installation path**: `/opt/myapp/`

**Execution from installation path** : `./myapp ?` --> Works fine. My application gets `?` as argument.

Copy myapp to different location `/home/`.

**Execution from new path** : `./myapp ?` --> The command line argument I get is `1` instead of `?`.

I understand *?* implies "*Match any one character*" in Fedora OS, but why does it work from installation path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `?` (*question mark*) to your shell script, you need to escape it.

Example `myapp.sh`:

```
 echo "The char is $1"
```

Usage:

> ./myapp.sh \?

Output:

> The char is ?

Without escape, it searches for file named only with one character.
If you had file in same folder as you script named `d`, it would output `The char is d`.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand ? implies "Match any one character" in Fedora OS, but why does it work from installation path?

Your understanding is inaccurate<sup>1</sup>.  What it actually does is try to match the argument *against a file path*.  So `./myapp ?` will look to see if there any files in the current directory with a one character filename:

- If there are, then it will replace the entire argument with one or more arguments containing the matches.
- If there aren't, the `?` is passed as-is.

Note that this process is often called *globbing*.  You can suppress it by quoting the `?` e.g.

```
 ./myapp \?
 ./myapp "?"
 ./myapp '?'
```

Also, note that a globbing wild-card (`?` or `*`) won't match a `.` at the start of a filename.  That's why `./myapp ?` and `./myapp *` won't match the `.` or `..` directories, or "hidden" files whose names start with `.`.

---

<sup>1 - This doesn't just apply to Fedora.  This applies to *any* shell that implements the POSIX shell specification.  That includes all extant versions of UNIX, Linux and MacOS X, as well as Windows 10+ WSL, Cygwin, MinGW, and many more.  It may also apply in contexts where applications implement shell-like behavior, though that will be application or programming language dependent.</sup>

---

Summary:

The reason that you got `1` rather than `?` in one case is that you were running the command in a directory that contained a file whose name is `1`.

The solution ... if you don't want the match ... is to quote the `?`.